# PHP exec and C++ Programm runs infinite

Tags: php, c++, bash

So I have a small PHP-snippet, which makes use of the `exec` function.
In my example, I run  this code:

```
// a bit setup before, but that is not too relevant for now
$jobs = count($redis->keys('*')); // outputs 10 if the job-amount is reached

if($jobs == 10) {
    exec("/usr/src/gx/examples/cpp/cpd/cpd01.out > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
}
```

First of all: I know, I don't have to separate them, but my knowledge in c++ isn't too deep and I really don't want to change the code, since it is a 3rd party lib.

For some reason, my PHP script doesn't run after reaching the 10 jobs. I can tell, that C++ script is called, but it seems like it never comes back to PHP.

I found similar threads and questions, but nothing so far helped

The C++ code shouldn't be that relevant, I think. I added it nevertheless.

In my shell, i just run my command with `./` or calling the full path: `/usr/src/ex/examples/cpp/cpd/cpd01.out` and everything works fine.

[C++ Code](http://pastebin.com/kdPQAFfV)

Any ideas?

// Update 1

I extended the code to this:

```
exec("/usr/src/gx/examples/cpp/cpd/cpd01.out > /dev/null 2>&1 &", $array, $status );
$redis->flushdb();
fwrite($fp, $status . "\n");
fwrite($fp, "------------\n");
fwrite($fp, print_r($array));
```

and this comes out:

```
0
------------
10
------------
10
------------
10
------------
1
```

Also, i just use `chown` the `cpd01.out`-file to `www-data:www-data`

Comment: Pardon me, but what part of this is C++?  All I see is PHP trying to execute a program (that could be written in any language).  I don't see any C++ source code or instructions for building a C++ program.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I added the c++ Code and added some more information

Answer (score 0):

First of all, does your user (the one who runs the script, www-data if apache) have permissions to run it?

If you define the second parameter as it will return you an array with the output for debugging purposes and a third argument with the exit status of your command (http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

```
if($jobs == 10) {
    exec("/usr/src/gx/examples/cpp/cpd/cpd01.out 2>&1", $array, $status);
    echo $status . "\n";
    var_dump($array);
}
```

Comment: See my update in the question. I used "chown" to change it to www-data:www-data and tried logged the output. Still not working I assume :/

Comment: I think you're not getting any output because the use of ` > /dev/null `. Plus, you are running it on background. I would remove that too for testing.